# How to ask for permissions in a Android app built with unity?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I'm working on an AR-based Android app in Unity Engine. But I'm unable to ask for Camera permission when the app starts on a mobile device. I have included permissions in the UnityManifest.xml file, but still not getting the permissions pop-ups. Every time I have to give permissions manually on phone.

This is my UnityManifest.xml

```
<!-- GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application android:isGame="true">
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.arcore-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="c8f8e11e-0c30-4e36-8c0c-f779764a3099" />
  </application>
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a framework within Unity to request permissions before you need them.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-RequestingPermissions.html